# Binary Tree using standard containers

Tags: c++11, data-structures, binary-tree

I want to store a binary tree where each node is a T type. Due to the absence of standard tree container, I suggested this way:

```
    std::map<size_t,std::pair<T,T>> my_tree;
WHERE:
    size_t : the depth
    std::pair<T,T> :left and right branches
```

I do not feel that it's a professional way.. Any suggestion?
P.S. I do not prefer 3rd-party library.
thanks :)

**EDIT**
My solution is wrong not just not professional. I do not know what I was thinking about.

Comment: Well, the implementation of std::map is usually a binary tree as is.

Comment: I did not get, may you please write an example declaration code line ?

Comment: What do you need in a binary tree that `std::map` does not offer?

Comment: you can just use std::map and it will be as good as using a binary tree, since std::map is usualy implemented as binary tree.

Comment: @nwp I need it to store the result of hierarchical clustering (dendogram).

Comment: @DavidHaim I will check some reference about it , thanks.

Comment: Ok, a `map` will not help you with saving hierarchical clustering. `map<size_t, pair<T,T>>` will not work unless all depths are unique, which is not guaranteed. You could use a `vector<tuple<T_parent, T_child, Distance>>`, but if that is clever depends on how it is used. Do you just need to draw it? Restore it from disc and convert it to something?

Comment: @nwp all depth should be unique, is there a case that it is not unique ??
my requirements are just read it from disc then reach each depth clusters.